# Is there a way to alias a query of the type "table.column" inside a function?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, common-table-expression

I created a CTE, the second part of the CTE contains a select with a st_contains. In this one, i've two columns of diferent tables with the same name. I want to alias one of this 'table.column' combination becouse when I do the selection at the end of the CTE outputs an error; column reference "  " is ambiguous.

```
with
   table1 as (
   ...
   ),         
   table2 as (
   select*
      from table3, table4
      where st_contains (table3.atribute1, table4.atribute1)
)
select
   table1.atribute1      
   table2.atribute1      #here i need somethig like table2.table3.atribute1
   from table1
   join table2 on table1.atribute2=table2.atribute2
;
```

I hope i explined the problem well.
Thanks!

Comment: Your with clause has to contain one or more valid  sql statements. Your second one lacks a select list. Also there is no opening paren. `table2 as ( select table3.attribute1 AS whatever FROM ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alias the table3 and table4 columns in your table2 CTE to resolve the ambiguity.

```sql
with
   table1 as (
   ...
   ),         
   table2 as (
   select table3.attribute1 table3atrr1, table4.attribute1 table4attr1
      from table3, table4
      where st_contains (table3.atribute1, table4.atribute1)
)
select
   table1.atribute1      
   table2.table3atrr1 -- use the aliased column name
   from table1
   join table2 on table1.atribute2=table2.atribute2
;
```